# How can I define a structure of physical constants?

Tags: c++

I would like to define some sort of structure (struct? namespace? class?) of physical constants that will be known globally to my program. The purpose of doing so is to allow me to give the constants simple, intuitive names while protecting those values elsewhere. For example, I could define q within this structure to be the fundamental charge without having to worry about accidentally using q as a loop variable somewhere else in the program. My thought was to define a struct (in main.h):

```
struct constants {
    float q=1.6022e-19;
} _C;
```

but that gives me the error

```
main.h:79: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'q'
main.h:79: error: making 'q' static
main.h:79: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'q'
```

I searched both here and the internet at large but didn't find an answer. If you know of one, please redirect me. I'm also fairly new to both Stack Overflow and C/C++ so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Which error please??

Comment: Sorry. Hit return before I was ready. Still getting used to this forum.

Comment: Do you compile with C++11 (or later) enabled ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Most definitely not, or it would work ;-)

Comment: What are you using? C or C++? The answer is different for each one.

Comment: @milleniumbug it's C++. Using a namespace (as suggested below) seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

one solution would be a set of static variables in a "constants" namespace:

```
namespace Constants
{
    static double constexpr Q = 1.3;
}
```

to refer to the variable, you would do:

```
Constants::Q
```

you can also define static variables within classes or structs as well, if that makes sense and keeps the code more organized.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks.  Haven't usen't constexpr much because I am still on VS2012 compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You either use

```
struct constants {
    static const float q=1.6022e-19;
};
```

or even better place these constants in a namespace

```
namespace constants {
    static const float q=1.6022e-19;
};
```